# ¿Cómo puede leer los datos que hay en un documento obtenido como referencia de otro documento en Firebase Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

En un documento de Firestore uno de sus campos es una referencia a otro documento.

Yo accedo a todos los campos normales dentro de un código como este:

```
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference breviarioRef = db
            .collection("liturgia").document("breviario")
            .collection("oficio").document("20190204");
    breviarioRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    if (document.contains("himno")) {
                        DocumentReference himnoRef = document.getDocumentReference("himno");
                        String textTitulo=  document.getString("titulo");
                        String textHimno=himnoRef.toString();
                        Log.d(TAG,textHimno);
                        mTextView.setText(Utils.fromHtml(textHimno)+textTitulo);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Por ejemplo, el valor que recupero en `textTitulo` es un valor normal, de tipo `String`, y lo muestra correctamente.

Pero el valor que hay en `himno` es una referencia a otro documento. No logro leer ese valor.

La referencia está ahí, pues el log cat me muestra algo como esto:

```
D/AboutActivity: com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@8e9bf8
```

Pero no sé cómo leerlo.

Ahora muestro el documento al que estoy accediendo en primer término:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el otro documento que está referido en el primero. Yo quiero obtener el valor que hay en el campo llamado `texto`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto de la mejor manera posible?

Answer (score 0):

Estoy trabajando en flutter y me sucedió algo parecido.

Cuando realizas un,

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

,creas una instancia de tu base da datos, en ella se encuentra implicita la referencia "/".
Cuando realizas un,

```
DocumentReference breviarioRef = db.collection("liturgia").document("breviario");
```

estas accediendo a la referencia "/liturgia/brevario",entonces cuando te refieres a la referencia,

```
DocumentReference himnoRef = document.getDocumentReference("himno")
```

,ya tienes la referencia lista, solo debes acceder al campo que necesites del documento "himno",

```
himnoRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                String textoHimno = document.getString("texto");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Algo así, no recuerdo la sintaxis.

Comment: Terminé haciéndolo así, más o menos. Pero mi idea era evitar `N` lecturas por cada campo del tipo referencia, de modo que pudiera recuperar todo en una sola lectura. O sea, algo parecido a consultas con `JOIN`. Cuando vi que Firestore tenía campos del tipo referencia pensé que servirían como un tipo de llave foránea pero no logré hacerlo. Lo que pasa es que en mi diseño habría varios campos del tipo referencia y para armar un contenido entonces tengo que hacer una lectura más a un snapshot por cada uno de ellos y es lo que quería evitar.