# ¿Como debería consultar un campo dentro de una subcoleccion que puede estar en diferentes documentos?

Tags: java, android, sql, google-cloud-firestore

Se que la pregunta es un poco confusa, pero para hacerme entender voy a colocar la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que ocurre es que dos personas se van a relacionar con un `chat`, entonces el `request` lo crea la persona 1, y la persona 2 lo acepta para que empiece el chat.

Ahora bien, debo mostrarle los `chats` que tiene la persona 2, lógicamente para que ingrese a ellos. El problema es la consulta que debo hacer; ya que la persona 2 no tiene un `chat` en todas las `request` entonces no estoy seguro si debo consultar las `request`una por una, y dentro de cada una buscar si la persona 2 tiene un chat ahí, o si puedo recorrer directamente las diferentes `request`y consultar la subcoleccion de `chat` para ver si existe directamente sin necesidad de hacer dos consultas diferentes.

Comment: **Por ahora** parece que no es posible. [He planteado una pregunta parecida a la tuya](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/235201/29967) hace un par de días y ninguna respuesta. [Luego pregunté en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54534278/5587982), donde tengo por ahora dos respuestas, pero no he logrado que nada de lo que me indican funcione. Leyendo más he visto en algunas partes que no se puede (por ahora) y que incluso lo han sugerido para futuras actualizaciones de Firestore. Creo que llegará tarde o temprano. La maravilla sería que funcione como una llave foránea.

Comment: Vaya, que mal. Espero que no tarden en colocar esta característica, es algo necesario y útil.